# How to be able to vertically scroll terminal to see all data from a large table

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to see all the data I have in a PostgreSQL table, but as there is plenty of data to make the data fit horizontally I use:

```
\x auto
```

and then:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Nevertheless I can only see one record and cannot scroll but if I expand my terminal then I can see some more of that data but not all.
How to see all the data using vertical scroll?

Comment: what pagination you use? (if any). try `\pset pager off` - do you see more rows now? can you use scroll now?..

Comment: What do you mean (what specific commands are you talking about)? I just use the terminal as it is and I'm afraid I don't know enough to answer you...

Comment: type `\pset pager off` in same window where you typed `\x auto`

Comment: Yes, it worked! Could you please make this an answer an explain the command you used?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You probably have paging on. If the pager you use is `more` (or `less`) you should be able to "list results" by pressing a space bar.

Run `\pset pager off` to switch paging off. This way `psql` will show you all rows and you will be able to scroll them vertically.

Comment: Thanks also for the pressing a space bar tip.